# Drop Down Box HTML Not working

Tags: html, select

So, I'm practicing making forms, and I'm currently trying to make a drop down list, which is easy, but, I keep running into a problem. When I create the list, the first option gets an error unlike the others. When I run the source, the one with the error is not shown, and I do not understand why. Does anyone know why?

Here is my code,

```
    <center><strong
    <form action="file:///C:/Users/someuser/Desktop/HTML/book.hml">
    <p>What months are your favorite?</p>
    <select name="months"
        <option value="june">January</option>
        <option value="june">June</option>
        <option value="december">December</option>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
    </select>
    </form>
    </strong></center>
```

[As some people may be able to see here, that the first option gets an error for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ESlq.png)

[and here, is what it looks like on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwVV3.png)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: His is example is there, but it's in the form of a PNG.

Comment: you need to close the `select`  (opening) tag (i.e. add closing `>`)

Comment: also missing closing tag for opening `<strong` tag

Comment: your code is not clean:
1- you should try to close each tag properly,
2- you can not add an <input /> tag between a <select></select> tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `<select name="months"` is missing the closing bracket.

```
<select name="months">
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem 1:
You missed the ">" on the select tag. Fix it.

Problem 2: 
Two of the options have the same values. What you want is:

```
 <option value="january">January</option><option value="june">June</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be a closing bracket after months.

Answer (score 1):

Please add `>` sign after `<strong` and `<select name="months"` Those are supposed to be there to ensure valid HTML code ;)